# Ajax AutoCompleteExtender.. can I pass two strings to my webmethod?

Tags: ajax, autocompleteextender

I got it working where I pass a string to my webmethod and it does a nice auto complete box...

But now I need to pass two strings to help filter the results. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using ContextKey to send second string. In this case you'll need to add a third parameter to your webmethod signature.

Comment: can you give some idea about how will I assign a value to the contextKey?